# SQL Server export temporary tables created in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, export-to-excel, temp-tables

I work with SQL Server 2012 and create a multi-user application. I work with a stored procedure which changes data matching the input. The stored procedure consists of different SQL statements and is quite complex.

I don´t want the user to change data directly in my database, so I use temporary tables. I want to export the customized temporary tables to Excel.

Is that possible? I already figured out how to create XML data, but creating Excel sheets would be easier for me.

Comment: You can export to CSV that Excel can open.

Comment: You can generate a report with SQL Server Reporting Services : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or execute BCP in the SP to extract the data as csv?